# Why is "Expires" 1981?

Tags: php, session, expires-header

My CRON Job returned an error that CRON job did not work. In that this was there:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2t2drultihqci4em15nbfmeb63; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

I am wondering why is `Expires` set to "1981". What is the significance?

Comment: Personally, I'd put 1984 there, just to screw with people's heads. ;)

Comment: Why? What's the significance of 1984?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four for a common connotation of 1984

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It's an attempt to disable caching.

The date is the birthday of the developer [Sascha Schumann](http://schumann.cx/) who added the code.

From session.c:

```
Authors: Sascha Schumann <sascha@schumann.cx> 
         Andrei Zmievski <andrei@php.net> 

// ...

CACHE_LIMITER_FUNC(private)
{
    ADD_HEADER("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    CACHE_LIMITER(private_no_expire)(TSRMLS_C);
}
```

Comment: Then happy birthday to him! ;-P

Comment: Omfg. I could've searched on for hours. - Thanks!  
See  

http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php
add session_cache_limiter('public') before session_start() to enable caching

Comment: Was Sascha Schumann drunken or what??? Is this the fine art of programming to add private birthdays into Source Code???

Comment: @Ingo Why is it a such big problem?

Comment: @klenium: Because it is not intuitive! It should be a default Date like: 1.1.1900 etc. Then you not need such a thread.

Comment: For anyone wanting to see the commit itself, the GitHub commit can be viewed here in the PHP source, committed on Dec 12, 1999: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/996216b4991f74c749d7c47df817daa7ec2f1740

Answer (score 10):

HTTP Expires header

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

It is set to negative or past value, to prevent caching of response.

Quite common usage of this header.

Comment: Yes...but as I know a session must expire at some point in time(unless I am wrong)....having the expiration date to 1981 how can we achieve that?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou obviously, session will expire on different terms (and server-side session might last longer than user-side session). Expires header only tells user-browser, to not cache the response and request given URL again, if user requests it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are using `session_cache_limiter` before calling `session_start`. If argument is `private` or `no-cache` the result is setting the `Expires` header to the time you have mentioned. Refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) document for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody just put `expires = date('-30 years')` (paraphrased) in his code to make really sure the content is set as expired and not cached.