# massive Issue with Caching and ModExpire on php Files

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I do have a massive Issue with Caching and ModExpire on php Files if i'am using following in my global .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml "access plus 600 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
 <filesmatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
 </filesmatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    ExpiresActive Off
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
</ifmodule>
```

If i am running a php file, which is returning a value and saving sth. in a MySQL DB, i have to reload twice or three times until all is done right.

I also had tried the following on the specified file without success
(as mentioned here [How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp) )

```
<files folder/file.php>
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
 </ifModule>
</files>
```

same if i put no-cache inside the folders htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent php files from caching try to remove `ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml`, which is for PHP.

IMHO you can also remove `FilesMatch` for PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

The two "ExpiresByType" lines are probably the reason for this problem as you have already identified.

Your .php files return documents of type text/html or application/xhtml-xml. So the headers being set by FilesMatch *.php contradict the previous entries. Which one is then chosen? I don't know.

Generally, the results of PHP file execution should rarely be cached.