# Laravel FileZilla upload/download

Tags: laravel, filezilla

Is there a proper explanation as to why when I'm either pulling the complete project from the server, or pushing it on server, views don't get updated? I always have to manually go to the resources folder and transfer views after everything has already uploaded/downloaded.

Comment: have try cleaning the views cache ?

Comment: so you mean that files actually do get uploaded, but the cache is pulling old versions? Why would it work then when I manually upload it without clearing the cache?

Comment: I think it checks that the file has been modified and rerenders the cached view. Or you skip uploading the views directory in the first upload.

Comment: Yeah, but how is uploading everything different than uploading a single folder? It should get rewritten in both cases

Comment: Because when caching is set to the file system(default). The caching of the views is litterly stored in files. So when you upload everything you upload the old cache. This also might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to clear your cache like stated in the comments.

```
php artisan view:clear
```

The reason why this is happening is because by default the caching is set to File. Which means that the view-cache is stored in files. When you upload everything the old-cache is uploaded. The files are stored in `storage\framework\views`

If you upload a single folder, laravel notices a change and the cache is busted.

PS: it is recommended that you use git for this kind of stuff, Laravel has .gitignore files to prevent this kind of behavior.