# Laravel 5.5 Project cpanel upload issue (file_put_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

My laravel 5.5. application works fine in my local machine. But problem is when I upload this application in **CPanel** it shows a warning `file_put_contents(D:\xampp_7_1_11\htdocs\googlebus\storage\framework/sessions/jD1o3Xbdu74IZKS4ryiRlzCI1GUFEUltAlwzTrtC): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and my site is not running.

Comment: you need to clear caches and config cache

Comment: I run `php artisan cache:clear` command. But still not working.

Comment: open this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server/44776169#44776169

Comment: Make sure the OS in Cpanel is windows. this is because the path "D:\xampp_7_1_11\htdocs\googlebus\storage\framework/sessions/jD1o3Xbdu74IZKS4ryiRlzCI1GUFEUltAlwzTrtC" just can work in windows.

Comment: I have clean cache file manually and it works fine. but `php artisan cache:clear` is not working for me, probably there my folder permission issue. Thanks, everyone.