# Does not clear cache in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, browser-cache

I have view file, I make some changes in there but I don't look changes in browser.

I put next command (it doesn't help me):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I followed the answer on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475921/9829082. It worked on Laravel 5.4 and 5.5 for me. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Are you editing the file in `resources/views` or in `storage/framework/views`? Is this possibly browser caching? (Cleared via hard-refresh, `CTRL + SHIFT + F5`, `CMD + SHIFT + R`, etc). What's the change that you made? Likely going to need some more information.

Comment: @TimLewis I editing in resources/views/user . I delete cache from browser it doesn't help me. I make any edits (for example add <h1>some text</h1>) but it doesn't change in browser. When I do finding by folder  i see my view file in two place - resources/views/user and storage/framework/views. Of cource I delete in  storage/framework/views, but it doesn't help me. It's magic for me. What can I do else?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You'll see the content in two places, but there's no reason to edit anything in `storage/framework/views`; those are generated from the files in `resources/views`, so editing them will be overridden pretty quickly. Adding an `<h1>` and refreshing the page _shouldn't_ require the cache to be updated, so I'm not sure why your content would be caching like that. Perhaps your server is doing something? Beyond my scope of knowledge unfortunately...

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for help. In my case work only renaming file(full answer you can se below). I don't understand what that, really, may be it's server problem, not Laravel problem

Comment: That sounds like a frustrating workflow... Glad I could be of some help regardless; hopefully someone else knows a bit more about this and can give you some more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just rename file and it's help me. For example, 
edit.blade.php->editt.blade.php->edit.blade.php
After that I can do any edits and it's work. But I don't understand why it happens.