# Access denied for user 'medindinDB'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) is not working now

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, environment-variables

Everything was working fine till my last visit to my website. But now when I try to access my website, it displays this error.

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'medindinDB'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from 'inventory')`

None of the code has been changed. I have also tried to clear cache as directed in this question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650432/8582983

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=inventory
DB_USERNAME=medindinDB
DB_PASSWORD=********
```

My website is hosted on cpanel.

Comment: `from 'inventory'` is incorrect syntax but that doesn't explain the message. The output of the SQL also is strange, did you do output a query after? Could you please add your code with credentials redacted?

Comment: Please add the PHP code. You have a database and table with the same name?

Comment: yes. The problem here is the database connection. I have a database with the name of inventory. @user3783243