# laravel app changes in files not reflected on web page

Tags: php, laravel, web, shared-hosting

I have a laravel application (v4.2) running on godaddy shared hosting. The application was working fine until recently when i had to make some changes i noticed that the pages are not reflecting the changes being done on the files. Both on controller and view files. I change text in a view template and changes reflect once then i undo or change it again and it wont change on the browser anymore. I have tried deleting the views content in the storage directory and still no help. The only thing that works is if i write a brand new route and load it once but again after another load it wont show changes unless i change the route name to something new. The application works fine on my desktop with the changes showing instantly. Anyone else have this issue or know how to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like there's another level of caching happening somewhere. (I'm sure you have but I have to ask) Have you tried clearing your browser cache? I'm unaware of how godaddy's shared hosting is configured, but is there perhaps a setting somewhere that is setting your expires response header to be long lived (browser cache clear should answer that though or looking in developer tools). Then my next question would be if godaddy utilizes vagrant or another similar caching mechanism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 – Clear Cache in Shared Hosting Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server)

Comment: Iv tried to clear the cache from app level using the laravel commands but its not only effecting views its effecting logic in the controller where its not running as well when i modify something - i have tried browser cache. Im thinking its some sort of caching going on from the hosting side but cant seem to find anything. Iv tried contacting their support but still waiting for a response

Comment: Controller files aren't changing either? That's an odd one. How are you migrating these files to the server?

Comment: Iv just been editing directly on the page - i know its a crappy way but i rarely ever make changes to this app but i have never had this issue wtih this app before - then again i havent changed anything in a year

Comment: If you are loading a controller file into a text editor (i'm assuming something in the browser provided by godaddy?) and you save those changes, then go back to the file later and those changes are not there, my money would be that something is broken with their editor and it's not saving changes. If your editing the file, and you go back to it later (clear cache restart browser) and it still contains your changes but the logic is not being applied to the application....THAT...is super odd. You might pull a file down locally, edit it and give s/ftp a shot.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who has a similar issue it ended up being that the hosting company (godaddy) had added a firewall to the account which was doing its own caching. I had to disable caching on the firewall level or disable it or clear it for it to start working