# Laravel is loading the wrong file

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-controller

I have my own server where I host the app while we work on it. The client has FTP access to the server. There is a controller called `CarDetailsController.php`. My client wanted to make some changed to the file, so he copies the file in the same folder, named it `backup_CarDetailsController.php` and changed the original file. 
After removing the backup file, I get the following message:

> include(/home/../../app/Http/Controllers/backup_CarDetailsController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

When I restore the backup file, the backup file is loaded and everything in it works. Any changes to the original file are not visible. He said he didn't change any other files.
I've checked, and routes file and everything is as it should be.
I have tried to clear the cache using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server), but it didn't help.
Since I have a cheaper plan, I do not have access to the terminal, so it would be great if the problem can be solved without it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this answer from your guide link https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475921/4650866