# Laravel not displaying latest changes on blade pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

UPDATE: Seems that the source of the problem is MAMP on M1 Mac. Clearing the caches via artisan commands did not work but stopping and restarting mamp servers (apache, php) seems to be working. I tried to clone the project to an old intel Mac. It worked fine. My guess is MAMP on M1 Mac has some problem of its own.

I'm developing a site using Laravel 5.8. on macOS 11.6 with MAMP.

I'm making changes on a blade page then go to browser and refresh to see the results. Somehow latest changes not reflected to the page. For example I add a simple `<h1>Hello!</h1>` tag and save the file. Switch to the browser, refresh and content is not there. Sometimes content shows up immediately and sometimes I have to wait for 10 to 30 seconds.
I tried to clear caches (view, config, routes etc.), restart MAMP servers. The problem persists.

Comment: did you try running `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: I think i have mentioned that in my question: "I tried to clear caches (view, config, routes etc.)...". It did not work.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to start using Docker instead of MAMP, that is not professional, even if you are learning. Docker is the future and the current present. You could maybe solve that issue by start using a real VM or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Run: php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:cache

Comment: I think i have mentioned that in my question: "I tried to clear caches (view, config, routes etc.)...". It did not work.

Comment: try this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel 5.8, you can use this artisan command

`php artisan view:clear`

or

`php artisan cach:clear`

if that does not work, you can find the views cache in the storage folder and delete it WHICH NO ONE WOULD PREFER.