# Changing the value of constant HOME in RouteServiceProvider doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-10

It seems straightforward as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating)

but for some reason changing the value of the constant `HOME` refuses to work. I changed

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

to

```
public const HOME = '/newhome';
```

but it still lands on `/dashboard` after login. I have rechecked the declaration of the routes, cleared the routes cache using `php artisan optimize` but it simply does not work.

I have worked the way around by using `Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('newhome'); })->name('dashboard');` but don't like it as it feels janky.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: ``php artisan optimize`` is not used to clear cache but to do opposite !! You need to clear using: ``php artisan optimize:clear``

Comment: are you using cutom  login controller? Probably there you might give a look or add the login controller code.

Comment: @OMiShah although adding `:clear` clears a few more items but it seems to have done the trick, thanks.

Comment: yes, it clear all caches including: view, config, route, cache and other compiled files. If you wish to clear only route you can use ``php artisan route:clear`` and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 – Clear Cache in Shared Hosting Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server)