# On click event for buttons don't have different behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some PHP and HTML:

```
<div class="bought">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="body">
                <?php if(Request::is('user/*')) { ?>
                <div>Did you buy this for <?php echo $user->username ?>?</div>
                <div class="options">
                    <a class="boughtyes cbutton whiteonpurple">Yes</a>
                    <a class="boughtno cbutton whiteonpurple">No</a>
                </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div>Bought?</div>
                <p>Click here to send hinters a message to let them know.<br />And yes, it can still be a surprise!</p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some jQuery that is supposed to simply bring up a JavaScript window with no or yes based on selection:

```
$("#view-hint .img .bought .boughtyes").click(function() {
    window.alert("yes");
});
$("#view-hint .img .bought .boughtno").click(function() {
    window.alert("no");
});
```

But whether I click the yes or no button it returns 'yes':

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Using chrome it looks like the elements are seperate:
[image]

EDIT2:
[image]

Comment: try shortening your jquery selectors to the element's class only, i.e. `$('.boughtyes')` and `$('.boughtno')`

Comment: [Works fine for me in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7ecwene/)

Comment: It worked fine for me when I tried it... Try adjusting your javascript to @Calimero's suggestion

Comment: @Calimero I shortened selectors and I am getting the same behavior

Comment: Are you sure the "yes" button doesn't overlap the the "no" button in CSS? Instead of `window.alert("yes");` put `window.alert($(this).attr('class'));` in both `click`s to see which button you're actually clicking.

Comment: ok, have you checked with your dev tools the boxes for both buttons don't overlap each other somehow (causing the click event on the first to be fired even when you click on the second) ? Another potentially useful test is to try clicking on other locations around the buttons and see what happens then.

Comment: I added a pic showing the buttons, it doesn't look like they are overlapping to me.

Comment: Yeah, but they BOTH have the same class `.buttonyes` ! Where is your `.buttonno` ?!!!!

Comment: @zealander Well that must be the issue! However, I don't understand why as my php file does in fact have buttonno used as a class. 2nd edit shows.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Try using Ctrl+Shift+R or clear cache? Also restart your server and check?

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional jQuery code that perhaps switches classes on the fly? The code you have shown would not produce this weirdness.

Comment: As an aside, `boughtyes` and `boughtno` are both types of _"bought"_ buttons, so the `bought` class makes sense, but the yes and no buttons are specific buttons, not a _type_ of button, so `class="cbutton" id="boughtyes"` would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `a` buttons have the same `class`:

[image]

Please correct them. That's the reason the `.boughtno` is not at all applied. See that they both have `class="boughtyes"`. Seeing your code, it is correct, which means, you need to hard refresh. Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or clear cache.

If you are using a framework like Laravel or Cake, please try restarting and compiling the assets again and try. I have used `vagrant`. For these I generally use:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Some info: [Laravel 5 clear views cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152102/laravel-5-clear-views-cache)