# View changes reflect only 60 seconds later in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having hard time trying to figure out why my view change only a minute later.

```
Route::get('/allo', function () {
    return date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")."Allo Allo";
});
```

In this example, When I change the text from `Allo Allo` to `Hello Hello` and reload the browser at `localhost:3000/allo`, the change take affect only a minute later.
I tried to empty the cache (as suggested in similar issues), restart the server, using cache killer extension but nothing change.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152102/laravel-5-clear-views-cache

Comment: I saw this before posting, I tried `php artisan view:clear` but it has any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `php.ini` file make sure:

`opcache.revalidate_freq=60`

is set to :

`opcache.revalidate_freq=0`