# Unable to Open my website in Safari

Tags: html, macos, safari

[image]I just bought a website in godaddy.com and also bought hosting. I uploaded my website files also, I gave the main page home.html title.
The site is opening in chrome and firefox. In safari it is still opening the default "coming soon" page. I even deleted the the default page from my godaddy server. I had opened the cpanel in safari only. 
Even on closing the wifi, the page still gets refreshed and opens the "coming soon" page.

Comment: Could you give us the url of the site?

Comment: willandconfidence.com The site is still underconstruction

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention. I cleaned the cache, history and even restarted my laptop. Still same problem

Comment: Then the issue will be server side caching, you can find more info on how to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried opening the website using www.willandconfidence.com/home.html
This worked. I guess there is a major issue with my mac and its not getting solved with clearing cache. 
Anyways for now I am able to access my website on safari.
Thanks everyone for the help. I appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cleared your browsers cache then the issue will be server-side caching. You can disable this while you work on your site by using a .htaccess file, you can find more information here: [How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp)

Comment: I dont know where to find .htaccess file

Comment: You will likely have to create one which can be done using a text editor

Comment: hey I didn't gave u -1 rating. Im doubting where clearing server side cache will do because the website loads even I turn off the wifi

Comment: Ah, it is most certainly some sort of browser side caching then as I can see the site in my Chrome. Please give this guide a go and see if it works for Safari: http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/17/empty-cache-safari-mac-os-x/

Comment: I tried clearing safari cache on my machine. I will try your other solution of server side clearing. Can you tell how to write .htaccess file. I dont anything about it.

Comment: I can load the site and don't get the under construction page, the problem isn't server side and is something affecting on your local Safari. Maybe try clearing the browser cache and also rebooting your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your website loads just fine on my safari. Clear your browsers cache by following these steps https://guides.instructure.com/m/4214/l/334964-how-do-i-clear-my-browser-cache-on-a-mac

Comment: I didn't gave u -1. I tried your solution but its not working

Comment: I guess your issue is fixed by now. Or are you still seeing this.

Comment: Im still seeing this but I have found a way around (read my answer). Im waiting for two days to choose my answer as solution (rules of this site).

Answer (score 0):

Hit CTRL + F5 on PC, not sure what it is on mac (might be shift+command+r). This will force refresh and clear all cache. IF that doesn't work, try clearing server side cache

Comment: no that command is for reading mode. I tried clearning cache so many time already.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a mac. Have you cleared the server-side cache? Otherwise, I have no idea what the issue may be as it's very weird, considering it works on all other browsers and you've cleared cache. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: its okay. I dont know how to clear server side cache.

Comment: Try this :https://uk.godaddy.com/help/clearing-the-server-cache-using-website-accelerator-8057