# Apache 2.4 - Never expire to all files, except 'index.html'

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-expires, gulp-rev

I'm using gulp-rev-all for my Angular based WebApp and I don't want to revision index.html. All other files are revisioned by gulp-rev-all, so they will change their names after each deploy.
How to tell Apache to not cache index.html (always fetch index.html from the server), but all other files in my WebApp must never be expired until I deploy new revision?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over here, it's some config that will turn off caching based on a pattern:

[How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp)