# How to disable caching in Bitnami Magento Stack entirely

Tags: apache, magento, caching, bitnami

I am using the Bitnami Magento 1.9 Stack and want to disable every kind of cache. I made these attempts:

1. I disabled Magento Caching ([as described here](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-disable-caching-within-magento.html))
2. I disabled Apache2 Caching ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724596/6580199)) for (html|htm|js|css|phtml|php) and checked the HTTP-Header [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423097/6580199)
3. I disabled Browser Caching with [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn)

Unfortunately, my phtml-files are still being cached. CSS- & JS-files are gladly not changed anymore.

Is there any further cache that I have forgotten to disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one last cache which I had not yet disabled:
OPcache
It is installed by Zend.

To disable this cache, open the file php.ini (in my case C:\Bitnami\magento-1.9.2.4-2\php\php.ini) and set
`opcache.enable=0`

(solution from [Bitnami Wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_AMP_Stacks#How_to_disable_cache_when_developing_in_top_of_AMP.3f))