# How to avoid browser caching of CSS, JS and image files using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[images|css|js]/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?ver=2 [L]
```

Now am using this code. But its not working.

Comment: Just comment that lines. Which framework u r using?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this using htaccess, stack we are using is HTML,Angular,Core PHP

Answer (score 1):

**Htaccess solution :**

You might want to use `mod_headers` functions `Cache-Control` and `Expires`, for the file types you want the browser to not cache :

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

[Source](http://www.era404.com/info/disabling-caching-with-htaccess/)

**PHP solution :**

You could also load each resource with a different timestamp each time your page is shown :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?time=<?php echo mktime(); ?>" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/myfile.css?time=<?php echo mktime(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

A few other options too:

**Browser hard refresh (Chrome)**

> Ctrl + F5 (or Ctrl + refresh button)

**Time stamp after the CSS files (instead of time, use some sort of version control)**

```
<script src="myjsfile.js?t=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

**HTML meta no cache**

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

**.Htaccess** (thanks to top answer here: [How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/how-to-prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp))

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```