# How do I avoid caching of a job-generated file in a static site?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, caching, static-site

My project is a mostly static site generated with [Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jekyll/info).
Most of the pages are just informational (hence static), but people can register with their address, so there's a registration page written in PHP.

My question is about a page with a Google Map, with a marker for each of these addresses.

I'm using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059129/6884), I just made a few minor changes, like separating the data (the list of GPS coordinates) into a separate JavaScript file, so I basically have something like this:

#### `data.js`:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

#### `map.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>address map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

    <!-- this should never be cached! -->
    <script src="http://example.com/data.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* a lot of JavaScript to show the map with markers */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`map.html` is static and (almost) never changes.
`data.js` (containing the addresses of all existing registrations) is re-generated by a cronjob once per day.

### How do I make sure that everyone is always seeing the newest version of `data.js` all the time?

I read about [Cache busting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9692665/6884), but I think I can't use it.
As long as `map.html` is a static file, I can't use either of the two cache busting approaches shown in the link.
(because each time I regenerate the .js file, I'd have to change the link in the HTML file)

Of course I could re-generate the HTML file as well, but I'd like to avoid the complexity if there's another solution.

#### Do I need cache busting at all, when I know the file will always change in a fixed interval?

The site is hosted on rented LAMP webspace, so I could tell Apache [to NEVER cache the .js file](https://serverfault.com/a/157715/1747).
But this will cause all clients to **always** re-load it, even though it only changes once each day.

So I could just set the caching time to 24 hours? *(because the file is re-generated once per day)*
Is it really that simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this? Should work in both .htaccess, httpd.conf and in a VirtualHost (usually placed in httpd-vhosts.conf if you have included it from your httpd.conf)

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Source: [How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/how-to-prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp)

Comment: Okay, this was clearly a case of "couldn't see the forest for the trees" :-)