# ErrorDocument - set no cache

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have an redirection when 404 is served with apache:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://my404.com/image.jpg

# other rewrite rules that cannot be affected
```

How can I set `no-cache` header only when redirection above is applied?

Answer (score 1):

From this answer [How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/how-to-prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp) put the folowing code at `.htaccess` file :

```
 <filesMatch "image\.jpg$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
 </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: I'd like to set `no-cache` only for 302 redirection that `ErrorDocument 404 https://my404.com/image.jpg` generates; not an every image file.

Comment: this is not for every image , only for the image.jpg which you redirect all wrong requests to it

Comment: Ok, but includes it 302 response itself? I mean, the stub image can be cached (it is on separate domain) but 302 redirection should not be cached.

Comment: sorry, there is no 302 here it is only 404