# Chrome does not show the updated page after successfully uploading new files to the server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use Hostinger for hosting. Although I uploaded my files successfully, Chrome won't show the changes, while windows Explore does. It seems that the browser remembers the old version of the page and doesn't download the new files. It's the same on my friend's computer and phone, whom I showed the page before the update.

The page is pure HTML, CSS, and a bit of JavaScript. How can tell my browser it's a new version of a page? Without manually clearing the browser history etc.

[www.michalrucinski.com](http://www.michalrucinski.com)
https://github.com/michalrutz/porto

Answer (score 0):

You could rename `index.html` to `index.htm` so the old file would longer exist and the browser would be forced to search for an alternative file.

Or you can set up cache control in the HTTP headers, e. g. [using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724596/3174790) if your hosting plan supports it.

Comment: You're right it's because of the cache. Clearing manually the cache fixed it. I'll have to learn how to make it automatical. Thanks for your help.