# What happens if the origin web server sets the expires value in response header as a time which is passed relatively long ago?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

What happens if the origin web server sets the expires value in response header as a time which is passed relatively long ago.

For instance, consider current time is Fri, 25 Jan 2013 GMT, and the expire header is set as -->

Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT

How will the client respond for the above instance?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Responding with a past date in the `Expired` header (earlier than the `Date` header value) makes no sense and would be a sign of some serious misconfiguration. That being said, clients would treat such response as "already expired" and not cache it. Same applies if `Expires` date is equal to `Date` header value (which is the correct way of server marking the response as "already expired") or having an invalid format.

See the [Expires section of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) for details.

Comment: The "serious misconfiguration" part of that response is probably a bit exaggerated. Some frameworks (Drupal for instance) send an Expires header in the past willingly to prevent caching by old proxies/clients.

Comment: @Lyrkan To add context to your comment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194481/why-is-expires-1981

Answer (score 3):

An expire time pointing to a specific and fixed date in the past is often seen in relatively poor configs and/or relatively poor (starters) code whereby the intent is to prevent the HTTP 1.1 client to cache the response. This will work, but a *specific* and *fixed* date in the past is plain ridiculous. A value of `0` would make more sense, or a value exactly equal to the `Date` response header, which is less often seen, but recommended by the [HTTP `Expires` header specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21), cited below (emphasis mine):

> ...
>
> HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats, **especially including the value "0"**, as in the past (i.e., "already expired").
>
> To mark a response as "already expired," an origin server sends **an Expires date that is equal to the Date header value**. (See the rules for expiration calculations in section [13.2.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.4).)
>
> ...

#### See also:

- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) - you'll see that some of the lower rated answers mention a specific and fixed date in the past, which just evidences ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2):

```
If an origin server wishes to force a cache to validate every
request, it can assign an explicit expiration time in the past to
indicate that the response is already stale.
```

This makes clear that it is a valid behaviour, and that  a client should treat the response as stale and validate it on every subsequent call.