# Why does WordPress use 11 Jan 1984 as an anti-caching value for Expires headers?

Tags: wordpress

The Expires header [can be set to a date in the past to prevent caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536401/what-happens-if-the-origin-web-server-sets-the-expires-value-in-response-header), although this seems to be regarded as an unusual practice. Any date before today should work for this purpose, but Wordpress [uses the very specific date of `Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT` for some reason](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nocache_headers/). I'm pretty sure that WP is the origin of this practice since all discussions involving this date appear to be about WordPress, and [this article](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/php/php-http-caching) specifically calls out the Expires header value as a sign of a WordPress server. [This blog post](https://www.cryptobells.com/wordpress-trivia-part-2/) remarks upon the unusual date but has nothing very useful to offer about it (unless the cache control headers are meant to honor the death of Fritz Geissler).

It seems to me like it would have been better practice to choose a more generic timestamp like `1 Jan 1900 00:00:00 GMT` to avoid surprise at the specificity. It has demonstrably caused some degree of confusion (albeit not much), as can be seen [from this forum post](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/expired-header-1984.616459/). Does anybody know what this date's significance is or why the WordPress developers chose it? I can only assume it's some kind of Easter egg, but it'd be neat to find out the details.

Comment: Maybe it's a birthday, or a date special to one of the original coders? So, "Easter egg".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like this goes back to [WordPress version 2.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/2.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L837).

Doing a bit of digging, the first use of this date in a `functions.php` was [in commit 2623](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/2623/trunk/wp-includes/functions.php), where it was used in the `nocache_headers()` function.

Prior to that, it had been copied & pasted around a few times. I think the first instance of this was [commit 1983](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1983/), where the non-cachable date in one case was changed from the birthdate of "Michel" (maybe Michel Valdrighi?) to the 1984 date. The message on that commit is:

> Don't cache. No, really. Hat tip: Kimmo Suominen.

That commit came from Matt Mullenweg, whose birthday is listed as 11 January 1984 [by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Mullenweg).

Comment: Great digging! Thanks for the research.

Comment: ...that's some awesome sleuthing!

Comment: In changeset 1983 you can see the date already used in `wp-comments-post.php`. It was changed there actually 3 days earlier in [Changeset 1964 for trunk/wp-comments-post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1964/trunk/wp-comments-post.php) by (surprise, surprise) saxmatt, as well.

Comment: Too bad, this anti-caching practice does not work. Chrome and Firefox (and probably Edge) all ignore it and serve Wordpress from cache, even claiming a 200-OK response code instead of 305-not changed. As observed today! In addition, my iframe also gets served from cache, although I just uploaded it afresh (the html).