# Symfony response cache controll headers duplicate

Tags: php, symfony, header, silex, http-caching

I am running into a problem (on different hostings) and I cannot really change host settings so I am looking for PHP solution.

When I am sending response to browser (Symfony's HttpFoundation\Response) some headers are duplicate and they contradict themselves. Than browser will not cache them.

PHP code

```
    $response = new Response(
        $html,
        200,
        array(
            "content-type" => "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        )
    );

    $response->setCache(array(
        'last_modified' => $page->getEditedAt(),
        'max_age'       => $staticCache,
        's_maxage'      => $staticCache,
        'private'       => false,
        'public'        => true,
    ));
```

Some of headers in browser

> Cache-Control:max-age=1800, public, s-maxage=1800
>
> Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>
> Date:Tue, 01 Oct 2013 15:08:39 GMT
>
> Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Pragma:no-cache

But my page should be public and cacheable. Where are the rest of headers set and how can i turn them off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is overriding your caching settings, that "Expires" date is very specific and included in the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L1227). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194500/2779152) stack overflow answer, it is the developer's birthday.

You can turn this off by changing the [session.cache-limiter setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter) in your php.ini. The [session_cache_limiter function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) page has more information about the possible values to set here. Try setting the value to public or to nothing and testing again.

You can see what the current value of the session.cache_limiter setting is with a small test page which echos the value:

```
<?php

echo(ini_get('session.cache_limiter'));
```

You said you are looking for a PHP solution, since you cannot edit host settings. You can change the value inside your code using the [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.