# Redirects stopped working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, http-headers, http-status-code-302

I'm stumped, my website was working fine and now on Firefox suddenly the redirects stopped working.
I've tested IE and Chrome and going to `/login` redirects me to `/dashboard` however on Firefox the page is blank (no output sent) and no errors are logged. So this is why I'm assuming it to be a browser related issue. It might be due to a firefox update, but not sure how to confirm that.
Here are the headers:

### Request Headers

```
GET /login HTTP/1.1

Host: local.example.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0 FirePHP/0.7.4

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

DNT: 1

Cookie: __utma=34805930.947644602.1372214584.1380730296.1380733154.30; __utmz=34805930.1378700053.15.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utma=214248714.242656582.1377296111.1380047082.1380734348.30; __utmz=214248714.1377296111.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __qca=P0-705514134-1378344178153; __utmc=34805930; __utmb=34805930.15.10.1380733154; __utmb=214248714.5.10.1380734348; __utmc=214248714; PHPSESSID=lli8i30qkhvohfm9ufkbdvbki0

x-insight: activate

Connection: keep-alive
```

### Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 17:30:58 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Pragma: no-cache

Location: /dashboard

Content-Length: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

It all looks pretty standard to me, however FF stays stuck on `/login` Am I missing something?
This behaviour is both on my local windows host and my remote amazon Linux web-server. The body is empty...

How could I go about debugging this?

Comment: Is your web site public? If yes, is it possible to get an hyperlink to the problem?

Comment: Are you redirecting with Apache or PHP?

Comment: Can you try `curl --include http://local.example.com/login`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Expires` [header field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in the response is really off. Firefox probably does not bother to render stale responses.

Please check the system time in your server. It is [possible it is an Amazon problem](https://serverfault.com/a/513329), but it is also possible that one of the server users set the system time.

You can look into setting up a [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (NTP) client to run regularly (with `ntpd`), if you don't have that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but googling that date results in 60,000 results. It's to prevent caching. Also this thread explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194481/why-is-expires-1981

Comment: @Moak: I wouldn't have thought the timestamp was worth googling. Thanks for the tip and the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire up [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what bits actually went over the wire. Among other information, Fiddler will show what content type is actually used during the HTTP request / response.

Answer (score -2):

This could be related to the fact that there is no extension.  Firefox could be having trouble determining if this is a document or folder.  Try firebug and see what URL Firefox tries to request after the redirect.