# multiple PHPSESSID cookies and browser doesn't keep any

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I'm getting 2 PHPSESSID set cookies headers from a login request from my yii application.

```
Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 02:19:44 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3lkhjlsv967n56horpcl3n7gl5; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Pragma: no-cache 
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=sctb6cd1snbd5g2esv1mn2lug7; path=/ 
Content-Length: 3 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And browser doesn't keep any and doesn't send back them for future requests. Any idea how this is happening?

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` more than once?

Comment: Expires 19 Nov 1981 ?

Comment: No, only once. By $session = Yii::app()->getSession(); $session->open(); http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#open-detail

Comment: @imanis_tn I have another website use the same yiiframework, it's login also sends expires header as above. But it works fine. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194481/why-is-expires-1981?rq=1

Comment: You should really be [setting a unique session name](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#setSessionName-detail) for each app.

Comment: Are you calling another controller/action from within your controller?